# MATLAB - variable in .dat file save command

Tags: image, matlab, save

I am converting a .tif image to double format, and the new filename is stored in a variable. When typing the save command, the script executes but the file is not saved unless I manually type 'New-file-name.dat' into the save command (in place of the variable). That is, the variable in the save command is not working.

Am I missing something I'm doing wrong here?

CODE BELOW

```
%user image selection    
[imagerawname imagerawpath] = uigetfile('*.tif', 'Double Convert - Select raw image file', directory);    
%create image location string    
imageloc = strcat(imagerawpath, imagerawname);    
pack    
%read and convert to double    
image=imread(imageloc);    
imagedbl=double(image);   
%save as .dat file    
savepath = strcat(imagerawpath, imagerawname(1:(end-4)), '-Dbl', '.dat')    
save 'savepath' imagedbl -ascii    
fprintf('\nDouble conversion saved.\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you are saving to a file named `'savepath'`. Try this:

```
save (savepath, 'imagedbl', '-ascii')
```

Comment: I've tried all combinations of syntax I can think of for the save command

i.e.

save savepath imagedbl '-ascii'
save(savepath, imagedbl, -ascii)

etc.  The weird part is it doesn't throw any errors my way...it just executes without saving the file..?

Comment: Try printing your `savepath`. Are you sure the file is where you expect it to be? The above [should definitely work](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html).

Comment: I've been running it twice to save. First to retrieve the generated save path, which I copy into the code to save it the second time it's run. Save path is working. This confuses me :(

Comment: Did you try with parenthesis? Also please print out the `savepath` variable and tell me what it is.

Comment: I added quotes to the variable name in your save command, since you're using the parentheses notation.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta savepath is anything from a two-line path to simply  'C:\CorrectedImages\SaveTest.dat'. Tried parenthesis.